# How to evaluate a mathematical expression saved in nvarchar variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mathematical-expressions

i want to evaluate a mathematical expression saved in a variable in sql server

i google this a lot and found 3 solution but not applicable in my scenario

1- this solution ***cannot be executed inside a function*** but i need it inside a function

```
declare @expression nvarchar(max)
set @expression = '2*3*100'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select @result = ' + @expression

declare @result int
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result int output', @result = @result out

select @result
```

---

2- this ***cannot be saved into a variable*** but i need to store the result into a variable

```
DECLARE @LocalVariable VARCHAR(32);
SET @LocalVariable = '2*3*100';
EXEC('SELECT ' + @LocalVariable);
```

---

3- the last solution i found ***gives me a error***

```
DECLARE @x xml 
DECLARE @v decimal(20,4) 
SET @x = '' 
DECLARE @calculatedDataString nvarchar(1000) = '(1 div 100)*((118 div 100)*300.000000)' 
SET @v= @x.value('sql:variable("@calculatedDataString")', 'decimal(20,4)') 
SELECT @v
```

***the error is***

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 5
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
```

---

***please advice***

Comment: The simple answer is you can't. You must use dynamic sql for this kind of thing and you can't execute dynamic sql in a function.

Comment: what can i do :(

Comment: Why does it have to be a function? Can you use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: because it is used by many other functions to send parameters and receive a return value

Comment: could you please help me on this ... this is working in a function but give an error on converting
... DECLARE @x xml 
DECLARE @v decimal(20,4) 
SET @x = '' 
DECLARE @calculatedDataString nvarchar(1000) = '(1 div 100)*((118 div 100)*300.000000)' 
SET @v= @x.value('sql:variable("@calculatedDataString")', 'decimal(20,4)') 
SELECT @v

Comment: Then you are stuck. You either need to store the calculated value or forget using a function.

Comment: Can you explain how that xml code is working but it gives an error?

Comment: this code gives an error ...... DECLARE @x xml DECLARE @v decimal(20,4) SET @x = '' DECLARE @calculatedDataString nvarchar(1000) = '(1 div 100)*((118 div 100)*300.000000)' SET @v= @x.value('sql:variable("@calculatedDataString")', 'decimal(20,4)') SELECT @v

Comment: Yes that code produces an error. But you also said it is working. Does it work or not?

Comment: it is applicable inside a function but gives an error on execution .. i mean it compiles correct but give an error in runtime .. this means if the error solved it will execute inside a function ... i think

Comment: could you help me to solve this error :) please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139414/discussion-between-sean-lange-and-mariam).

Comment: what is this chat

Comment: Probably there is a simpler solution, can you give us a broader view, why you need the feature. Probably @Cappelletti's solution can be adapted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this may help.

The following will evaluate a series of expressions, save the results to a #temp table.  From there you can store the individual results into a variable

This is a dramatically scaled down version.  The full one was built for macro substituions (i.e. calculate a series or Finanancial Ratios for multiple datasets)

If you provide a more robust USE CASE, perhaps I can help further

**Example**

```
Declare @Expression table (ID int,Expression varchar(max))
Insert Into @Expression values
 (1,'(1/100.0)*((118/100.0)*300.00000)')           -- Simple Calculation
,(2,'datediff(DD,''2016-07-29'',GetDate())')       -- System Functions
,(3,'(Select max(name) from master..spt_values)')  -- Select Value From Table
,(4,'convert(date,GetDate())')                     -- Get Today's Date


IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Results
END
Create table #Results (ID int,Value varchar(max))

Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
Select  @SQL = @SQL+concat(',(',ID,',cast(',Expression,' as varchar(max)))') From @Expression 
Select  @SQL = 'Insert Into #Results Select * From ('+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'values')+') N(ID,Value)'
Exec(@SQL)

Select * From #Results

Declare @Var decimal(10,4) = (Select Value From #Results where ID=1)
Select @Var  -- 3.5400
```

**Temp Table**

```
ID  Value
1   3.54000000000000000
2   243
3   YES OR NO
4   2017-03-29
```

Comment: for this  '(1 / 100)*((118 / 100)*300.000000)'  it gives 0.00

Comment: @Mariam int/int return and int,

Comment: @Mariam (1/100.0)*((118/100.0)*300.00000)

Comment: @Mariam I added your test in the answer

Comment: @Mariam Just a couple of points,  1) The ID is an int, but this be a more descriptive string (i.e. InterestRate).  2) In create #Results, value is set to varchar(max) to support multiple data type.  This can be a numeric value if that is you end goal

Comment: dont run within a function

Comment: Msg 2772, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CalculateElement, Line 123
Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.

Comment: Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure CalculateElement, Line 127
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.

Comment: @Mariam It nerver would.  Dynamic SQL is simply not allowed in functions.   As you well know by now, SQL Server does not have an EVAL() ... it would be great if it did.

Comment: @Mariam I've had great success in this area, but I would need a better understanding / visual of what your endgame is

Comment: @Mariam SQL by design is declarative,  If you don't want dynamic SQL, then the next option is CLR.

Answer (score 2):

The last your solution fails because `SET @v= @x.value('sql:variable("@calculatedDataString")', 'decimal(20,4)')` does not evaluate the expression, it tries to cast `@calculatedDataString` to decimal which definitely must fail in most cases.

The only solution I know is CLR function. You may wish to look at this project https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET

It creates `SQLNET` UDT with methods you can use, kind of

```
SELECT  SQLNET::New(@calculatedDataString).EvalInt()
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/registering-user-defined-types-in-sql-server for how to register UDT in sql-server.

Comment: my 2 concerns 1- can i save this to a variable 2- can it be used inside a function

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 4, Line 6
Type SQLNET is not a defined system type.

Comment: Yes, you need to install UDT from the above project in your DB first. And yes, its methods can be used in a function and to assign a value to a variable.

Comment: aha but i dont know how to install UDT i never worked on such installation

Comment: Not so simple but doable. See the last link in the answer.

Comment: i am stuck with this microsoft explanation is there any other example on how to create udt

Comment: when i Add a User-Defined Type class it is added as a .sql file not .cs file and cant rename it

Comment: The project https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET doesn't contain binaries so you need to build it yourself. Download source code from the project page. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8s4s5dz(v=vs.100).aspx for  more hints about deploying CLR UDT.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution that's been in production for years. Amazing there isn't a provided solution given the power of RegEx.

This is using a safe CLR assembly which does presume some server level access. That means this might not work in some cases of AWS RDS, or anything other than managed instances of Azure SQL (like the new "server-less" option).

I'm presently testing an implementation of R language in an Azure SQL instance that has this very limitation. Thanks to: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4748/sql-server-2016-regular-expressions-with-the-r-language/

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [TESTSCORING1_CLR_CS]
FROM 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
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EvaluateArithmethicExpression](@expression [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [float] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [TESTSCORING1_CLR_CS].[TESTSCORING1.ArithmeticCalculations].[EvaluateArithmethicExpression]
GO

-- Demo some simple evaluations
SELECT [dbo].[EvaluateArithmethicExpression]('1<10') as one, [dbo].[EvaluateArithmethicExpression]('1+1') as two, [dbo].[EvaluateArithmethicExpression]('300/100') as three
GO
```

Comment: The fact they haven't included any sort of Regular Expression in the Sql Server engine at this point is nigh on criminal! That is the ONE and only thing I still have any CLR assemblies left in the db for.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I implemented a pure T-SQL function which does compute basic arithmetic (`+ - / * ( )` and precedence). While I haven't benchmarked it, it's obvious that this solution will not be able to compete with CLR-based solutions. However, since it is pure T-SQL, it may be used in places where CLR cannot. This is not production-ready without adding lexical and syntax error handling code and testing it properly.

It's basically a single statement splitting the string into characters, then tokenizing these chars, and finally applying a shunting yard algorithm with two stacks stored as XML columns to compute the result.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fnEval(@s nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS float
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Token Types:
    -- -1 => error
    -- 0 => whitespace
    -- 1 => number
    -- 2 => opening parens
    -- 3 => closing parens
    -- 4 => operator + -
    -- 5 => operator * /
    DECLARE @result float;
    WITH cteChar AS (
        SELECT 0 ix, CAST(N' ' AS nchar(1)) c, 0 iType, 1 iGroup -- Anchor
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT LEN(@s)+1, NULL, 3, -1 iGroup -- Finalizer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.ix+1, CAST(SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1) AS nchar(1)), CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1) LIKE CASE WHEN c.iType=1 and c.c=N'e' THEN N'[0123456789\+\-]' WHEN c.iType=1 THEN N'[0123456789.e]' ELSE N'[0123456789]' END ESCAPE N'\' THEN 1 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1)=N'(' THEN 2 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1)=N')' THEN 3 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1) IN (N'+', N'-') THEN 4
            WHEN SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1) IN (N'*', N'/') THEN 5
            WHEN RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1))=N'' THEN 0 
            ELSE -1 
        END, CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(@s, c.ix+1, 1) LIKE CASE WHEN c.iType=1 and c.c=N'e' then N'[0123456789\+\-]' WHEN c.iType=1 THEN N'[0123456789.e]' END ESCAPE N'\' THEN c.iGroup 
            ELSE c.iGroup+1
        END
        FROM cteChar c 
        WHERE c.ix<LEN(@s)
    ), cteToken AS (
        SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(c.ix)) AS int) ix, STRING_AGG(c.c, N'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.ix) s, c.iType
        FROM cteChar c
        WHERE c.iType>0 -- We could handle lexical errors here
        GROUP BY c.iGroup, c.iType
    ), cteParser AS (
        SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cteToken f WHERE f.ix>2) THEN CAST(0 AS bit) ELSE CAST(1 AS bit) END bResult, t.ix+1 ixNext, CASE WHEN t.iType=1 THEN 
                (SELECT t.s [@val] FOR XML PATH(N'operand'), TYPE) 
            END xOperand, CASE WHEN t.iType>1 THEN 
                (SELECT t.s [@val], t.iType [@type] FOR XML PATH(N'operator'), TYPE) 
            END xOperator
        FROM cteToken t
        WHERE t.ix=1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE WHEN p.xOperator.exist(N'/*')=0 AND t.s IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END, t.ix+CASE WHEN (t.iType>3 AND t.iType<=p.xOperator.value(N'*[1]/@type', 'int')) OR (t.iType=3 AND NOT p.xOperator.value(N'*[1]/@type', 'int')=2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
            CASE 
            WHEN t.iType=1 THEN 
                (SELECT t.s [@val], p.xOperand.query(N'*') FOR XML PATH(N'operand'), TYPE) 
            WHEN (t.iType>3 AND t.iType<=p.xOperator.value(N'*[1]/@type', 'int')) OR (t.iType=3 AND NOT p.xOperator.value(N'*[1]/@type', 'int')=2) THEN
                (SELECT CASE p.xOperator.value(N'*[1]/@val', 'nchar') 
                    WHEN N'+' THEN
                        p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/*[1]/@val', 'float')+p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/@val', 'float')
                    WHEN N'-' THEN
                        p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/*[1]/@val', 'float')-p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/@val', 'float')
                    WHEN N'*' THEN
                        p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/*[1]/@val', 'float')*p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/@val', 'float')
                    WHEN N'/' THEN
                        p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/*[1]/@val', 'float')/p.xOperand.value(N'*[1]/@val', 'float')
                    END [@val], p.xOperand.query(N'*/*/*') FOR XML PATH(N'operand'), TYPE)
            ELSE
                p.xOperand
            END xOperand, 
            CASE 
            WHEN t.iType=1 THEN 
                p.xOperator
            WHEN (t.iType>3 AND t.iType<=p.xOperator.value(N'*[1]/@type', 'int')) OR (t.iType=3) THEN
                p.xOperator.query(N'/*/*')
            ELSE
                (SELECT t.s [@val], t.iType [@type], p.xOperator.query(N'*') FOR XML PATH(N'operator'), TYPE) 
            END xOperator
        FROM cteToken t
        JOIN cteParser p ON p.ixNext=t.ix AND p.bResult=CAST(0 AS bit)
    )
    SELECT @result=p.xOperand.value(N'/ *[1]/@val', 'float')
        FROM cteParser p
        WHERE bResult=CAST(1 AS bit)
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
    RETURN @result;
END
```

Comment: I'm confused, I've used this function before and loved it, but now I"m trying to install it on another SQL server dataabase and I'm getting syntax error: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnEval, Line 71 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '('.`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @MAW74656 That's not enough information. What SQL Server version, which DB compatibility level? Have you copied this into its own file? Does the DB use non-standard settings for ANSI compatibility, quoted identifiers etc.?

Comment: 2017 Enterprise edition compat level 100.  Nothing non-standard.

Comment: Oh, its STRING_AGG(), isn't supported in this compatibility level.  I missed that.  No big, I'll look at alternative for that bit.  Great function overall, thanks!